# Find the length of an Array consisting of 2D arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to find the length of this array, and all the sub arrays inside it. Meaning 13 and not 6? Without having to use loops and adding up all the elements inside the arrays.

I'm looking for one command that can do this.

```
[1, [4, 5, 2, 1], 2, [4, 5, 2, 6], 2, [3, 3]]
```

Comment: with third party libs only (or manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but you can do

```
arr.toString().split(',').length
```

`join(',')` would work as well, it flattens everything

```js
var arr = [1, [4, 5, 2, 1], 2, [4, 5, 2, 6], 2, [3, 3]];

console.log(arr.toString().split(',').length)
```

if all you wanted was the number of indices in total

---

If the array contains commas inside the indices, those could be removed for the same effect

```
JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/"(.*?)"/g,'1').split(',').length
```

Comment: @Maxx - that's why it's a hack, it works with the posted example, but not with everything else.

Answer (score 2):

try flatting it

```
[].concat.apply([], [1, [4, 5, 2, 1], 2, [4, 5, 2, 6], 2, [3, 3]]).length
```

Answer (score 1):

- [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) could be used but **[at your own risk]**
- Use [**`Array.isArray`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to determine whether the passed value is an `Array`.

```js
var input = [1, [4, 5, 2, 1], 2, [4, 5, 2, 6], 2, [3, 3]];
var length = input.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + (Array.isArray(b) ? b.length : 1);
}, 0);
console.log(length);
```

Comment: Thanks this helps too !

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost – But not up to the mark as compared to other answers :(

Comment: not generic also ) strings has `length` property too. `['12', [3,4]]` will return 4

Comment: @Maxx — And `object` can have length property as well (`{length:101}`)

Comment: @Rayon well, you'll have a bug or error in your app in production in this case

Comment: @Maxx — I doubt I will ever have such use-case in my app, I never had.. :(